# How to access template variables in the script section of my HTML file in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, html, templates, google-apps-script

I need to access templated variables in the script section of my HTML file. Specifically, I need to use `content.price`.

I can access `content.price` just fine in the templated section of the body of my HTML.

This behaves as expected.

```
<div class="container">
  Price: $<?= content.price ?></td>
  <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
</div>
```

But in the script section, trying to access `content.price` seems to be throwing an exception.

This causes the buttons to fail to render. (It fails silently.)

```
amount: {
  value: content.price //  '0.01' // Using content.price throws an error
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Code.gs

```
var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(HTML_FILENAME);
template.content = values;
var htmlOutput = template.evaluate();
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <!-- source: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/ -->
  <html>
    <body>
      <div class="container">
        Price: $<?= content.price ?></td>
        <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
      </div>
      <script
        src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=SB_CLIENT_ID">
      </script> 
      <script>
        // This function displays Smart Payment Buttons on your web page.
        paypal.Buttons({
          createOrder: function(data, actions) {
            // This function sets up the details of the transaction, including the amount and line item details.
            return actions.order.create({
              purchase_units: [{
                amount: {
                  value: content.price //  '0.01' // Using content.price throws an error
                }
              }]
            });
          },
        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In script section also you'll need to use template tags.

Something like these :

```
amount: {
  value: <?!= content.price ?>
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Care to help out on this one too? https://stackoverflow.com/q/60074230/1640892