# How to pass templated variables to server-side handler functions in HTML files using Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, templates, google-apps-script, server, handler

[Follow up to this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60073413/1640892) https://stackoverflow.com/a/60073413/1640892

I want to pass a templated object variable to a server side function in GAS. I expect to see the buttons render, then after filling out the payment details and clicking pay, I expect to see the `handleTxn()` function successfully execute using the `content` object as one of its arguments.

But, instead, nothing happens because the buttons do not even render. It fails silently.

```
var content = <?!= content ?>;
google.script.run.handleTxn(data, details, content);
```

How do I now access the `content` object to pass it to a server function?

Code.gs

```
[...]
var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(HTML_FILENAME);
template.content = values;
var htmlOutput = template.evaluate();
[...]

function handleTxn(data, details, content) {
  // do stuff
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <!-- source: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/ -->
  <html>
    <body>
      <div class="container">
        Price: $<?= content.price ?></td>
        <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
      </div>
      <script
        src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=SB_CLIENT_ID">
      </script> 
      <script>
        // This function displays Smart Payment Buttons on your web page.
        paypal.Buttons({
          createOrder: function(data, actions) {
            // This function sets up the details of the transaction, including the amount and line item details.
            return actions.order.create({
              purchase_units: [{
                amount: {
                  value: <?!= content.price ?>
                }
              }]
            });
          },
          onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            // This function captures the funds from the transaction.
            return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
              var alertText = (
                '\nWe charged you: $'
                +
                <?!= content.price ?>
              );
              alert( alertText );
              var content = <?!= content ?>;
              google.script.run.handleTxn(data, details, content);
            });
          }
        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: *expect to see the result of the handleTxn() function.* where ?

Comment: @TheMaster: I guess to be more clear, I should have said I expect to see the `handleTxn()` function successfully executed using the `content` object. I'll edit the question now to reflect that.

Comment: No. *It fails silently.* How did you come to this conclusion? What **tangible** result were you expecting? *expect to see the handleTxn() function successfully executed*  What makes you think it didn't execute successfully?

Comment: @TheMaster: First, I was expecting the buttons to render. And if they did not render, I was expecting an error message in the script execution transcript. But the buttons did not render and there was no error message.

Comment: Is this question about fixing button not getting render or how to pass templated vars ?

Comment: The error, if any, should be visible at  [browser console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Opening_the_Web_Console). I also do not understand what rendering buttons got to do with templated vars.

Comment: @UmairMohammad: The question is about passing templated variables. The button rendering is a symptom of making a reference to those variables in a way that is not supported.

Comment: Maybe we can comment out all the code that you suspect for not rendering the button ? Once button rendering is fixed, then we can fix passing templated vars ?